Deserialize with serde-xml-rs for a weird tag with arbitrary attributes
Heyo.  Say I've got the follow XML:
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<event time="2024-04-19T00:36:52Z">
  <detail>
    <_flow-tags_ ASV_h91="2024-04-19T00:36:52Z" />
  </detail>
</event>

How do I get the key-value out of the <flow-tags/> tag?  Is it possible with serde_xml?  Am I into custom deserializer/serializer territory here?
Is it even possible to grab the attributes' key-values as a map/list?

Yes, it's possible, you can just use a HashMap:
use std::collections::HashMap;

use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use serde_xml_rs::from_str;

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct Event {
    #[serde(rename(serialize = "@time"))]
    time: String,
    detail: Detail,
}
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct Detail {
    #[serde(rename = "_flow-tags_")]
    flow_tags: Vec<HashMap<String, String>>,
}

fn main() {
    let xml = r#"<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
        <event time="2024-04-19T00:36:52Z">
            <detail>
                <_flow-tags_ ASV_h91="2024-04-19T00:36:52Z" />
                <_flow-tags_ ASV_h91="2024-04-19T00:36:52Z" />
            </detail>
        </event>
    "#;

    let layout: Event = from_str(xml).unwrap();

    dbg!(&layout);
}

Just note that serializing is still an open issue and for now probably requires statically known attributes or some custom serialization logic.
